# Angular - Page reload causes partial to load instead of the whole page

Tags: angularjs

When I reload the website from the root (ex: website.com), the refresh is fine. However, when I reload from anywhere else (website.com/about), only the partial html for the about page is loaded, leaving out all the template code such as headers, footers, script imports, etc. In addition, the browser insists on loading website.com/about/ , including an ending slash.

Here is the relevant source.

**app.js**

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router'])

.run(function($state, $stateParams) {

})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "home/index.html"
    })
    .state('about', {
        url: "/about",
        templateUrl: "about/index.html"
    })
    .state('contact', {
        url: "/contact",
        templateUrl: "contact/index.html"
    })
    .state('news', {
        url: "/news",
        templateUrl: "news/index.html"
    })
    .state('vip', {
        url: "/vip",
        templateUrl: "vip/index.html"
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Comment: You haven't shown or mentioned which server you are using, but this has all the signatures of a server that isn't configured properly for html5Mode.  See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646843/angularjs-html5-mode-how-do-direct-links-work-without-server-specific-changes) which explains why is that happend in `html5` mode.
I also recommend you to use [`html2js`](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js)