# $locationProvider.html5Mode breaks routes - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've been looking at ways to remove the # from the URLS within AngularJS and found many solutions which pointed me in the direction to use what they had suggested now Inside my app.js I have the following:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', "oc.lazyLoad"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/home',
    {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/Home/home.html',
    })
    .when('/About',
    {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/About/About.html'
    })
    .when('/home/:page_number',
    {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/Params/params.html',
        resolve: {
            loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('Templates/Params/paramsController.js');
            }]
        }
    })
    .otherwise('/home',
    {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/Home/home.html'
    });


$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});

});
```

Inside the head of my SiteMaster.Html I've placed

```
 <base href="/">
```

Full breakdown:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script> <!-- Consists of Routing  -->
    <script src="Scripts/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <title>Angular Routing Tutorial</title>

    <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <h1>sitemaster Template</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Yet when I run this I get directed to /home  when I manipulate the URL to be /About I get

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

And the same for /home/SomeValue

Yet when I remove

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

And remove base href="/" from my SiteMaster.Html the routes work as expected?

Can someone explain to me why this behavior would be happening?

Comment: I think this is already answered here, anyway, first of all, if you set requireBase to false then remove the base tag and about the real issue... well, you'll need to configure your server in order to serve the index.html for all those routes to avoid that 404, so it is not an AngularJS problem but a web server's one.

Comment: Setup your server for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS HTML5 Mode - How do direct links work without server specific changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646843/angularjs-html5-mode-how-do-direct-links-work-without-server-specific-changes)