# Angular JS Pretty url conflict with cakephp

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm using `Angular JS` along with `cakephp` version 3.x. For pretty URL for angular js state routing, i used the following code to achieve.

Added in config,

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Added `base` in Pages/home.ctp (cakephp file. It's like an index.html)

```
<base href="/">
```

It actually works until i reload the page. Also, I've some controller and actions like example.com/contact, example.com/work etc.. which serves a normal php page.

**For example :**

Before pretty url :

I've a state url example.com/#/profile
Also I've a normal php page example.com/profile

This actually works until i added a html5Mode.

After adding pretty URL :

Angular JS state url becomes : example.com/profile (that's fine)
But if i reload that, it generally throws error as it's actually looking for general MVC page, not angular.

I'm sure that there's is conflict with Angularjs - Cakephp. Plus I've some authentication like only the logged in users can only access certain actions, if not they will be redirected to homepage.

I tried putting server side code in `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646843/angularjs-html5-mode-how-do-direct-links-work-without-server-specific-changes). You have to separate server side routes from client side routes and always serve index.php for any route not handled by PHP.

Comment: I've tried those. But none of them works.

Comment: You just need to configure server to route all requests (except for statics of course) and serve client application root page so that Angular can route from there. It's pretty simple. If you are using CakePHP it's even simpler, because I think there is already decent .htaccess.

Comment: @dfsq Can you put some code? I've tried some codes which are available in online but it doesn't worked.