# Deploy Angular in WebLogic Server

Tags: angular, weblogic12c

have built a basic angular 2 app. However I need to deploy it on Weblogic server. 
I could install it in Tomcat Server with the recommended configurations in the following post ([AngularJS HTML5 Mode - How do direct links work without server specific changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646843/angularjs-html5-mode-how-do-direct-links-work-without-server-specific-changes)), but in weblogic they don't work.

Comment: Can you publish some errors or something else that will show that you tried?

Comment: @user3838494 can u please tell me, how u deployed your angular project on WebLogic 12c Server, i am not able to deployed, new in Angular and Weblogic. please help me.