# Strange angularjs route behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following routes on my angularjs app:

```
 angular.module('index').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
                   function indexRouteConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

   var routeToUserHomePage = ['$injector', function routeToUserHomePage($injector) {
       var $location = $injector.get('$location');
       //somecode

       $location.url('/unauthorized'); // this works
   }

   $routeProvider
     .when('/', {
        templateUrl   : 'app/custom/templates/customTemplate.html',
        controller    : 'customTemplateController',
        resolve       : { routeToUserHomePage: routeToUserHomePage }
    })
    .when('/unauthorized', {
        templateUrl   : 'app/custom/templates/customTemplate.html',
        controller    : 'customTemplateController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        resolve : { routeToUserHomePage: routeToUserHomePage }
    });
```

If I access the url `http://localhost:8090/` it works perfectly and Im redirected to the `unauthorized` screen.

But if i go to the browser and type `http://localhost:8090/unauthorized` I get a **Error 404 Not Found** from the webserver. It even doesnt hit the "otherwise" route. What im missing here?

I have the `<base href="/">` tag on index.html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you've enabled the `html5Mode` and you don't have what it needs on the server.

> Server side Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)

Source: [AngularJS HTML5 Mode - How do direct links work without server specific changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646843)

Answer (score 0):

create a separate controller and template and then write the logic inside that controller

```
.otherwise ({
    url: '/unauthorized',
    controller: 'error',
    templateUrl: 'templateUrl.html',
});

function error($location) {
 // write whatever your logic
}
```

Comment: Actually i cannot do that, i have simplified the code on the routeToUserHomePage method. The problem is if i type http://localhost:8090/unauthorized and hit enter on the browser, i get an 404 error